# How do you enable error squiggles to pop up on the cpp file and not on the terminal?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have switched over from Codelite and Codeblocks and usually, they show the error on the CPP file with a red squiggly line, but on VSC they show it in the terminal. How would I enable it to show on the screen and my CPP file?

Comment: Did you setup `c_cpp_properties.json`

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Its in the documentation for Visual Studio Code: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference)

Comment: do you have a problem matcher defined in your task that does the build/compilation

Comment: @rioV8 I honestly have no idea

Comment: read the VSC doc about debugging and the C++ docs in particular for the compiler you use